# Unresolved reference: LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, layout-inflater

Inside `OnBindViewHolder` of my `RecyclerView` `Adapter`, I got multiple items. One of those (ITEM_TRATAMENTOS) got a setOnClickListener which has the purpose of create an `LinearLayout` when I click in an button (add_field_btn). The problem is that the only argument of `getSystemService` is unresolved (**Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE**).

In `ViewPagers` it works fine, but inside OnBindViewHolder, it's not the case.

```
 ITEM_TRATAMENTOS ->{
      val viewHolderTratamentos = holder as ViewHolderItemTratamentos
      holder.add_field_btn.setOnClickListener {
                    inflater = Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, null)
                    // Add the new row.
                    parentLinearLayout?.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout?.childCount!! - 1)
            }
  }
```

The expected result is to create the new line, which it works if it was on an normal activity.

Comment: `getSystemService()` is not a `static` method on `Context`. It is a regular (instance) method. You need to call it on a `Context` instance, not on the `Context` class.

IMHO, the best solution is for you to call `getLayoutInflater()` on your activity, then pass that `LayoutInflater` into the `RecyclerView.Adapter` via its constructor.

Comment: How can I call the getLayoutInflater in my activity? @CommonsWare

Comment: I am assuming that you are creating your `RecyclerView.Adapter` in an activity function somewhere. So, in that function, call `getLayoutInflater()`, and pass that value into your adapter's constructor.

Comment: Like this? : adapter= AdapterCaracterization( this, listSectionType = listSectionType)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, null)     It doesn't make any sense to me. So what about the getSystemService? @CommonsWare

Comment: I think here you just lack of an instance of context. It could be passed here in some way, or you could write a method somewhere that you could get the global application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to get the `LayoutInflater` from `parentLinearLayout` ViewGroup.

**Example**

```
parentLinearLayout?.apply { 
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) // context is now available in the receiver scope
    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
    addView(rowView) // Add the view to the last position
}
```

Also, be aware of the consequences of adding too many views without recycling them. Probably you'd need another `RecyclerView` if the number is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Add a `LayoutInflater` parameter to the constructor of your `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass.

Step #2: When you create the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, pass in a `LayoutInflater`, obtained from `getLayoutInflater()` on your activity.

For example, here is a `RecyclerView.Adapter` named `ColorAdapter`:

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2018 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _Elements of Android Jetpack_

  https://commonsware.com/Jetpack
*/

package com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter

class ColorAdapter(private val inflater: LayoutInflater) :
  ListAdapter<Int, ColorViewHolder>(ColorDiffer) {

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
  ): ColorViewHolder {
    return ColorViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false))
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ColorViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindTo(getItem(position))
  }

  private object ColorDiffer : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Int>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldColor: Int, newColor: Int): Boolean {
      return oldColor == newColor
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldColor: Int, newColor: Int): Boolean {
      return areItemsTheSame(oldColor, newColor)
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that my `ColorAdapter` constructor has `private val inflater: LayoutInflater` as a parameter.

Here is the activity that uses that `ColorAdapter`:

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2018 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _Elements of Android Jetpack_

  https://commonsware.com/Jetpack
*/

package com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val random = Random()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    items.apply {
      layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
      addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)
      )
      adapter = ColorAdapter(layoutInflater).apply {
        submitList(buildItems())
      }
    }
  }

  private fun buildItems() = generateSequence { random.nextInt() }
    .take(25)
    .toList()
}
```

Since you and I are both writing in Kotlin, the `getLayoutInflater()` call turns into a reference to the `layoutInflater` property on the activity. So, when I create my `ColorAdapter`, I use `ColorAdapter(layoutInflater)`, to pass in an instance of `LayoutInflater`.