# Kotlin/Android - Get the id of generated button inside onBindViewHolder Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I got a `recyclerView` with multiple items (`ViewHolders`). In one (**ViewHolderItemTratamentos**) of these I got the following elements:

[image]

When the first "add `button`" is clicked, through an `inflator` layout, the same elements (`editText` and `button`) are created beneath the previous ones. Just like this:

[image]
The code from my `adapter` (which got the logic of the set click) which create the new line:

```
holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {
    holder.parent_linear_layout.apply {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
        holder.parent_linear_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_linear_layout.childCount!! - 0)
        holder.add_field_button.text = "-"
     }
  }
```

So, **the problem** is that I can't get the `id` from the `button` of the `layout.used_products_field` to generate another new line. Should I inflate this layout (It does make any sense?)? And should I give the same `id` to every `button` (static and the generated one)?

Content of the R.layout.used_products_field:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:inputType="phone"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="@style/botaoCard"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: I think if you had the button always there just `visibility="GONE"` then you wouldn't be having these problems

Comment: @epicPandaForce Maybe You don't get the point. My problem is that I can't get the id of the second button, which is inside of a different layout from the first one.

Comment: @PedroRelvas You have another question without accepting the answer even you clearly are using it in this new question, and I mean the the part `val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981684/unresolved-reference-layout-inflater-service-inside-onbindviewholder/53983759#53983759

Comment: Just specify the `id` in `R.layout.used_products_field` as you usually do, later in you click listener call `holder.parent_linear_layout.findViewById(R.id.button)`

Comment: @OmarMainegra Hi! Sorry, you're right! Ii was not intended! Thank you for calling me to the attention.

Comment: @OmarMainegra I've tried that. Doesn't work it all. It can't reach the button.

Comment: NP, Post the content of `R.layout.used_products_field` to see what you are trying

Comment: @OmarMainegra Done. I've also tried an different id name in relation with the static one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the views inside the inflated layout (`used_products_field`)

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
val button = rowView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_field_button)
val edittext = rowView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.number_edit_text)
```

Comment: yes, but only works for the first button. If I have 16 buttons the other 15 won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the button after adding it to the parent `ViewGroup`, in your case is the row click listener block.

```
holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {
    holder.parent_linear_layout.apply {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
        addView(rowView, childCount!! - 0) // addView and childCount are available in the scope
        holder.add_field_button.text = "-"

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_field_button) // findViewById is available in the scope
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @OmarMainegra. The problem is that I can get the id in that way, but the next generated buttons don't got the action of the setOnClickListener. Do you know why? Thank you.